# ReactJS Material UI sticky footer not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, sticky-footer

How do I get sticky footer with ReactJS using Material UI. I tried this but not sticking to the bottom.

```
export default function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer style={{color: "gray"}}>
            <center>Copyright ...</center>
        </footer>
    )
}
```

Looks like there is no native support in materialui. Will be good if the solution does not use boostrap.

Answer (score 8):

You should use position `fixed` for footer:

```
<footer style={{color: "gray", position: "fixed", bottom: 0}}>
  <center>Copyright ...</center>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thought this worked but overlaps with content if browser height is reduced.

Answer (score -1):

This works for you

```
export default function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer className="sticky bottom-0">
            <center>Copyright ...</center>
        </footer>
    )
}
```

Comment: where do the sticky and bottom-0 classes come from?

Answer (score -2):

You can make your footer sticky with something like this

```
export default function Footer() {return (
    <footer style={{color: "gray", position: "fixed", bottom: 0}}>
        <center>Copyright ...</center>
    </footer>
)}
```